# What are some "don't-take-it-home" jobs in the IT industry?

Tags: careers

I have a masters in computer science and have worked several years as a consultant and programmer. While this was well paid, I did not find it very fulfilling.

I have realized that I need a certain amount of creativity in my life, and need to work on my own projects. The problem with most jobs I have encountered in the IT world, is that they drain from the same kind of energy that I need to have on my projects.

I would therefore like a job where I can show up, do a good job without draining too much creative energy, and let work be work when I leave for the day. It doesn't have to be well paid, it just need to cover my rent and some food.

Since I have both studied CS and have experience in the IT industry, I find it natural to look there. I would also like to work more with people, and spend less time in front of the screen (unlike most IT persons I know).

Does anyone have suggestions for such roles?

Comment: Can i ask for more details? Do you want to keep in IT? No management? So, working as a consultant and programmer did not helped with your creativity and they drained a lot of energy? You want roles close to you? Are you willing to move?

Comment: Managment is an option, but then the job quicky becomes draining. I need to feel some sense of purpose with what I am doing. I find helping people directly often do that. IT is not a must, but I figured it was the easiset place to look since all my education and experience is there.

Comment: Try to cut your consulting hours back to what you need to live, then do what you will with the rest of your time...

Comment: Database administrator - all you do is sit in the server farm all day and watch blinking lights, unless something goes wrong or there's a major deployment.  The pay is often way more than 'survival'.

Comment: Business analyst or government programmer (or PM)  on a long term project (they tend to be less stressful IT jobs often all the work is contracted out and you wend up just sttending meetings.)

Answer (score 4):

> I would therefore like a job where I can show up, do a good job
>   without drining too much creative energy, and let work be work when I
>   leave for the day. It doesn't have to be well paid, it just need to
>   cover my rent and some food.
>
> Since I have both studied CS and have experience in the IT industry, I
>   find it natural to look there. I would also like to work more with
>   people, and spend less time in front of the screen (unlike most IT
>   persons I know).
>
> Does anyone have suggestions for such roles?

Have you considered something in retail?

Best Buy has Geek Squad. Apple stores has Genius Bar. I'm sure there are others, and smaller  retailers may have even more of the attributes you indicate.

You can just show up and punch a clock in and out. You could get to work with people more and in front of a screen somewhat less. You don't have to bring work home with you. You won't drain much creative energy. And the pay will certainly not be too high.

Alternatively, consider switching to more of a Help Desk Technician role. In some companies, you would have plenty of people contact, and far less responsibility. My son held that position part-time in his High School and then his University at one time. Lots of walking around fixing printers and such. It didn't fit his idea of a career, but it was a good solid job and didn't tax his creative energy. (He was able to complete a lot of homework, while waiting for the next task.)

And if you become an independent contractor, you can pick and choose all of your gigs, and find ones that meet your personal needs regarding more people contact, less screen time, not spending too much of your creative energy and not bringing work home.

Comment: It certainly fits my description, but I would of course

Comment: Sorry, it got posted before I finished. I would of course like to use some of the skills I have acquired through studies and experience. I guess what I am asking is a lower level of responsibility

Comment: Try this question, finance or corporate IT sound ideally suited: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17795/is-the-amount-of-work-really-a-workplace-culture